# How would you encrypt/decrypt numbers in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography

Using Node.js [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) module it is quite easy to encrypt/decrypt strings, as string are readily supported. For numbers you would need to use Buffer/TypeArray or DataView types.

How would you encrypt/decrypt JavaScript numbers the most robust/efficient way possible?

Using:

- crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv[, options])
- 'aes-256-cbc'
- cipher.update(data[, inputEncoding][, outputEncoding])

Answer (score 0):

It depends how robust/efficient it needs to be.

Your easiest option would be to just `.toString()` any numbers and encrypt them as you would a string.

An arguably "faster" way would be to create a buffer of bytes to represent the number.  Assuming we have a 16-bit integer (for simplicity):

```
function toBytes(n) {
    const b1 = n >> 8;
    const b2 = n << 8 >> 8;
    return Buffer.from([b1, b2]);
}

function toNumber(buf) {
    let n = buf[0] << 8;
    n += buf[1];
    return n;
}

for (let i = 254; i < 258; i++) {
    const buf = toBytes(i);
    const n = toNumber(buf);
    console.log(n, "=", buf);
}
```

This is likely faster, but you'd need to be encrypting *a lot* of data for it to make a meaningful difference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A couple of questions:

Comment: .toString() would need a corresponding function to get back to number. Would parseFloat() work in every case?

Comment: That buffer example: I'm not sure what type the JS numbers are (64 bit of something maybe, and I'm not sure about endianness, maybe platform dependent). I was looking for an example that would work in every case for JavaScript numbers. Seems like that answer would need to take into account some bigger numbers?

Comment: Also, Node Buffer has functions like these:

- buf.writeBigInt64BE(value[, offset])
- buf.writeBigInt64LE(value[, offset])

Wouldn't they help? https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_writebigint64be_value_offset

Comment: @ile "numbers" in javascript are mostly just 64bit floats. 
 you'd also need to do more bit-fiddling if you want more than 2**16 values

Comment: @SamMason I would use .toString() to get to string and .parseFloat() to get back to numbers if that works in every case. So far it seems that it works. Do you have comment on this?